# smarty - how to output the variable "{$myvar@display}" 

Tags: php, smarty3

I can't seem to find a way to escape the "@" sign in a smarty variable output block.

Here's my setup:

```
$data = array("myvar@display"=>4534534);
$smarty->assign($data);
```

[Assign doco here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.assign)

In my template file:

```
<body>
 {$myvar@display}
</body>
```

**Output:**

```
Message: Undefined property: Smarty_Variable::$display
```

Any ideas how I can display that without changing the "@" sign (I am unable to modify this as it is a convention used throughout the application and I do not have control over this)

Running LAMP 5.2.17, Smarty 3

---

PS I've tried this without success...

```
{assign var=jason value="$myvar@display"}{eval var=$jason}
```

*output*

```
4534534@display
```

Comment: Why use insane variable names like this?! This convention sounds really stupid - especially since it actually causes technical issues.

Comment: be great to change it... but like so many other programmers i'm bound by a legacy of programmers who did what they did before my time...

Comment: Why not take a day to change those crappy variable names. That could probably even be done with a script.

Answer (score 2):

the only way that I see with smarty 3 (with tag {php} disabled) is assign a new variable.

If you have an access somewhere in php code, you can put in:

```
$smarty->assign('at','@');
```

and get the var name in tpl:

```
{$myvar{$at}display}
```

I think that's more simple than remake the logic behind your complex variable name.

Alternatively, You can try if you have the tag {php} enabled and get index of private smarty array.

EDIT

this works for me

```
{assign var=foo value='myvar@display'}
{${$foo}}
```